# array_count_values(): Can only count string and integer values

Tags: php

I want to find mean, median and mode of an array. I can find mean and median but but when I run the program, I get

> Warning: array_count_values(): Can only count STRING and INTEGER
>   values! in C:\AppServ\www\tez\tez2.php on line 40" error fore finding
>   mode.

I searched but couldn't fix it. Is there anyone who can help me with that ?

My Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Tez Deneme</title>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>

<?php
echo "Welcome to my project".'<br>'.'<br>'; 
$arr=array(1100,3150,4400,4400,5170,7450,7450,7450,8230 );

for($i=0; $i<=8; $i++)
{
    if ($arr[$i]<100) {
        $arr[$i]=$arr[$i];
    }else{
        $arr[$i]=$arr[$i]/1000;
        $arr1[$i]=$arr[$i];
    }
}

function calculate($arr, $output){

    switch($output){
        case 'mean':
            $count = count($arr)+1;
            $sum = array_sum($arr);
            $total = $sum / $count;
        break;
        case 'median':
            rsort($arr);
            $middle = (count($arr) / 2)+1;
            $total = $arr[$middle-1];
        break;
        case 'mode':
            $v = array_count_values($arr); 
            arsort($v); 
            foreach($v as $k => $v){$total = $k; break;}

        break;

    }
    return $total;
}

function sd_square($x, $total) { 
    return pow($x - $mean,2); 
}

function sd($arr) {
    return sqrt(array_sum(array_map("sd_square", $arr, array_fill(0,count($arr), (array_sum($arr) / count($arr)) ) ) ) / (count($arr)-1) );
}

if (isset($_POST['select'])) {
    someFunction();
}

echo '  '.'<br>';
echo "Values: ";
echo json_encode($arr).'<br>';
echo 'Mean: '.calculate($arr, 'mean').'<br>';
echo 'Median: '.calculate($arr, 'median').'<br>';
echo 'Mode: '.calculate($arr, 'mode').'<br>';
echo "Standart Derivation: ".sd($arr);
?>
```

Comment: Well, dump whatever you are passing to that function and ensure it is a string or int.

Comment: You have decimals in your array, change it to string

Answer (score 1):

In your code

```
$arr[$i]=$arr[$i]/1000;
$arr1[$i]=$arr[$i];
```

Your `$arr1` is a collection of floats:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1.1
    [1] => 3.15
    [2] => 4.4
    [3] => 4.4
    [4] => 5.17
    [5] => 7.45
    [6] => 7.45
    [7] => 7.45
    [8] => 8.23
)
```

Hence the `Can only count STRING and INTEGER values`.

You can round it or do something else like cast it to a string etc...

```
$arr[$i]=$arr[$i]/1000;
$arr1[$i]=(string)$arr[$i];
```

Also

```
function sd_square($x, $total) { return pow($x - $mean,2); }
```

The var `$mean` is undefined here.

Making those changes:

```
<?php

echo "Welcome to my project".'<br>'.'<br>'; 
$arr=array(1100,3150,4400,4400,5170,7450,7450,7450,8230 );
$arr1=[]; //<--- define this if all are < 100 its undefined
for($i=0; $i<=8; $i++){
    if ($arr[$i]<100) {  //<-- clean up formatting.
        $arr[$i]=$arr[$i];
    }else{
        $arr[$i]=$arr[$i]/1000;
        $arr1[$i]=(string)$arr[$i]; //<-- cast to string
    }
}

function calculate($arr, $output){

        switch($output){
            case 'mean':
                $count = count($arr)+1;
                $sum = array_sum($arr);
                $total = $sum / $count;
            break;
            case 'median':
                rsort($arr);
                $middle = (count($arr) / 2)+1;
                $total = $arr[$middle-1];
            break;
            case 'mode':
                $v = array_count_values($arr); 
                arsort($v); 
                foreach($v as $k => $v){$total = $k; break;}

            break;

        }
        return $total;
    }

function sd_square($x, $total) { return pow($x - $total,2); } //<--changed to $total
function sd($arr) {
    return sqrt(array_sum(array_map("sd_square", $arr, array_fill(0,count($arr), (array_sum($arr) / count($arr)) ) ) ) / (count($arr)-1) );
}

   if (isset($_POST['select'])) {
    someFunction();
  }

echo '  '.'<br>';
echo "Values: ";
echo json_encode($arr).'<br>';
echo 'Mean: '.calculate($arr, 'mean').'<br>';
echo 'Median: '.calculate($arr, 'median').'<br>';
echo 'Mode: '.calculate($arr1, 'mode').'<br>';
echo "Standart Derivation: ".sd($arr);
```

Output

```
Welcome to my project

Values: [1.1,3.15,4.4,4.4,5.17,7.45,7.45,7.45,8.23]
Mean: 4.88
Median: 5.17
Mode: 7.45
Standart Derivation: 2.4035743059961
```

[Sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/d37c14e7a0631688c4c4308e73097ee5a761b1a2)

Comment: It has to be decimal, can't I find mode of decimal array ? @ArtisticPhoenix ?

Comment: if it's technically a string you can.

Comment: You are my real hero! Thank you so much @ArtisticPhoenix

Comment: It was easy, no problem.